# Updating User Object

Tags: php, parse-platform

I got problems on updating user objects using PHP, I tried this code but nothing seems to work.

```
 $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
 $file->save();
 $currentUser=$_SESSION['user']->get("username");
 $userQuery = new ParseQuery("User");
 $userQuery->equalTo("username", $currentUser);
 $avatarObject = $userQuery->first();
 $avatarObject->set( "avatarImage", $file );
 $avatarObject->save();
```

`$currentUser` will print out of the Username, `$file` is working also. The problem is the querying. I can't seem to get any values.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: Unless I am missing something `$_SESSION` is an array and not an Object so I dont think this statement `$currentUser=$_SESSION['user']->get("username");` will work. Try `$currentUser=$_SESSION['user']['username'];`

Comment: when i print_r($userQuery) and $avatarObject i got nothing.

Comment: the $currentuser gives the value of the user and it works

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason why.
Need to declare

```
use Parse\ParseObject;
```

Before using it all the time
But I still can't read User class but other classes I can.

I got this when querying user class

> ```
> Parse\ParseQuery Object (
> [className:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => User
> [where:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => Array
>     (
>     )
>
> [orderBy:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => Array
>     (
>     )
>
> [includes:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => Array
>     (
>     )
>
> [selectedKeys:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => Array
>     (
>     )
>
> [skip:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => 0
> [count:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => 
> [limit:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => -1 )
> ```